# WP REST API - "rest_user_cannot_view" ONLY on specific users

Tags: javascript, rest-api

so upon requesting users through REST API - I get the

```
code    "rest_user_cannot_view"
message "Sorry, you are not allowed to list users."
data    
status  401
```

for example
https://www.example.com/en/wp-json/wp/v2/users/36

The problem is though, that I can request many of the users - but since adding new users, I get this error.

Tried incognito, using an OLD user - resulted into the same thing. No new plugins were added recently.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here - [Unable to get the info of the user which doesn't have created any post via REST API](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/331042/unable-to-get-the-info-of-the-user-which-doesnt-have-created-any-post-via-rest)

It is very weird - would've never thought of this.